# How to set dataset scheduling based on trigger time in Azure ML?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-ml-pipelines, azure-ml-component

I'm using Azure Machine Learning (Azure ML) to manage my machine learning workflows, and I want to set up dataset scheduling based on trigger time. The dataset I'm working with has a different format than the trigger time. For example, my dataset has the format "path_on_datastore/2023/01/01/some_data.tsv", while the trigger time format is different.

I have discovered that the scheduling function supports the use of "${{creation_context.trigger_time}}" as a PipelineParameter,(link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-schedule-pipeline-job?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=cliv2#expressions-supported-in-schedule) but the format it provides doesn't match the format of my dataset. I try to use the components to do that, but the components only support outputting the dataset. Is there a way to customize the format or adapt the trigger time format to match my dataset format?

Comment: are you importing the dataset or exporting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PythonScriptStep` class in Azure Machine Learning to execute a python script to get formatted data path based on trigger.
**Example:**
Python script file (`script.py`):

```
import datetime
# Trigger time is same as current_time
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    
# Format the current time to match the dataset path format
dataset_path = "path_on_datastore/{}/{}/{}/some_data.tsv".format(current_time.year, current_time.month, current_time.day)
    
# Use the dataset path in your further processing or operations
print(dataset_path)
```

With the script you can create a pipeline:

```
from  azureml.core  import  Workspace, Experiment, Dataset
from  azureml.pipeline.core  import  Pipeline, PipelineData, ScheduleRecurrence
from  azureml.pipeline.steps  import  PythonScriptStep
workspace = Workspace.from_config()

script_step = PythonScriptStep(
name="Get Dataset Path",
script_name="script.py",
compute_target="targetCompute",
inputs=[],
outputs=[],
source_directory="./",
allow_reuse=False
)
```

Then you can schedule the pipeline:

```
# Daily execution at 8:00 AM
daily_schedule = ScheduleRecurrence(frequency="Day", interval=1, hours=[8], minutes=[0]) 

pipeline = Pipeline(workspace=workspace, steps=[script_step]) 
pipeline_schedule = pipeline.schedule( start_time="2023-06-01T08:00:00", description="Daily pipeline schedule", recurrence=daily_schedule ) 

# Pipeline Execution
experiment = Experiment(workspace, "dataset_scheduling_experiment") 
pipeline_schedule.submit(pipeline_run=experiment.submit(pipeline))
```

To disable or update the schedule:

```
 # Specify the name of the pipeline schedule 
 schedule_name = 'your_schedule_name'  
 schedule = Schedule.get(workspace, schedule_name) 
 # Disable the schedule 
 schedule.disable() 
 # Update the schedule  
 schedule.update()
```

Above example explain how you can use **PythonScriptStep` class** and **current time** in datetime as **trigger time**.
For more information, please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-pipeline-steps/azureml.pipeline.steps.python_script_step.pythonscriptstep?view=azure-ml-py).
Note: Make sure to make changes in python script and datastore paths as necessary.